# Publish of tomcat 7.0 using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, publish

I am fairly new to setting up tomcat and eclipse. I am a java programmer and is trying to figure out how things work with web development.

On to the question, I can't seem to publish (if publish is the right term) any changes I am doing, whether on my .jsp or in my servlet to the server(which is my local machine) without restarting tomcat.

I tried restarting, publish option, clean, stop and start. Nothing works. Is there a problem with my configuration?

Under the publish menu when I opened the config of tomcat with eclipse, I chose "Automatically publish when resources change", it didn't work. I try to change it to Never publish automatically and then publish it myself, didn't work either.

Can anybody help me? Thanks! I don't want to quit eclipse everytime I change something with my program.

Comment: restarting, publish option, clean, stop and start should work.By the way can you check there is any temp folder in your deploy directory?If any then delete the contents of temp and clean then start.

Answer (score 0):

first check if your project was added to tomcat

after that check the path of the tomcat deploy and the path of your project { has to have the same value }